# Reference a web source using ACM reference style in WinShell

Tags: bibliographies, acm

I am a Windows user. I use MikTex and Winshell editor to edit my latex script. I am working on ACM conference style. I want to reference a web source in the following format as in their template:

> Rafal Ablamowicz and Bertfried Fauser. 2007. CLIFFORD: a Maple 11
>   Package for Clifford Algebra Computations, version 11. (2007).
>   Retrieved February 28, 2008 from
>   http://math.tntech.edu/rafal/cliff11/index.html

In WinShell, I have a .bib front-end view. I can choose the source type. I do not have a `web` in the list. So I use `misc`.

[image]

The problem is: how can I add this part: `Retrieved February 28, 2008 from` before the URL???

Here are some of the type of fields and no one is for: retrieved from :
[image]

When I tried to add the `retrieved from` it in the URL, it trims the spaces.

**EDIT:**
I use: `ACM-Reference-Format.bst`

This is the tex file part:

```
\bibliographystyle{ACM-Reference-Format}
\bibliography{sample-bibliography}
```

This the .bib entry for a web page which I do not know how to add: `Retrieved February 28, 2008 from` part that the ACM reference style require before the URL as in their page: [ACM reference format](https://www.acm.org/publications/authors/reference-formatting)

```
@misc{chrome17,
 author               = {Google},
 title                = {Chrome},
 url                  = {https://www.google.com/chrome/index.html},
 year                 = {2017},
 }
```

Comment: Can you give us a little more to go on? We need to know what bibliography package you use (you tagged your question with `biblatex`, but as far as I know there is no official ACM style for `biblatex`, so you could be using `ACM.bst`, i.e. traditional BibTeX). It would also help greatly if you could show the resulting entry in the `.bib` file and not just screenshots (i.e. the plain text `.bib` file). The most convenient form you can give us the information we need is an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864)/[MWEB](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864)

Comment: The reference format is: ACM-Reference-Format.bst

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With [`ACM-Reference-Format.bst`](https://github.com/borisveytsman/acmart/blob/master/ACM-Reference-Format.bst) you can add the date of access of an URL to the `lastaccessed` field (only for `@misc` entries, though).

```
\documentclass[format=acmlarge, review=false, screen=true]{acmart}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{elk,
  author       = {Anne Elk},
  title        = {A Theory on Brontosauruses},
  year         = {2016},
  url          = {http://www.example.edu/~elk/bronto.pdf},
  lastaccessed = {August 7, 2017},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\cite{elk}

\bibliographystyle{ACM-Reference-Format}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE]